# Looking for a sci fi novel regards finding a 'mythical' Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can any one tell me the name of a sci-fi novel in which characters in a spaceship hunt for a 'mythical' long forgotten Earth.

- They use 'rutters,' an ancient book which contains images of symbolic forms/animals that indicate how to traverse a path through the gateways.  The symbolic images/charts are coded stars/planets to be followed upon this journey.
- Earth is a long forgotten planet, almost a forgotten myth.
- The 'Rutter' is ancient and valuable.
- At the end of the journey Earth is hidden. It is found following further examination of the symbolism in the book/chart.

Comment: Welcome Jeremy. Sounds intriguing and slightly familiar. Check out our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it reminds you of any more details (when it was written - or when you read it, any cover-art, character details etc..)

Comment: Do you perhaps remember which year it was exactly when you read this? Was it a standalone novel or part of a series?

Comment: What is a *rutter*? [This?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutter_(nautical))

Answer (score 4):

That sounds a great deal like Melissa Scott's excellent "5/12 of Heaven" (published in 1985). It's is a pretty good match for the details including the books used for navigation -- though I don't remember them being called "Rutters".  I don't have a copy handy, but [this review/description](https://www.eyrie.org/%7Eeagle//reviews/books/roads-heaven-a.html) does a pretty good job of covering it.

Edited by @Danny Mc G
I have a copy and they are actually called 'starbooks' and are ancient tomes full of 'roads' showing space navigation routes